# How to push to Bitbucket repository with access token?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, git, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I used to get the access token from Bitbucket

(with the help of this documentation https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/OAuth+on+bitbucket#OAuthonbitbucket-ObtaininganOAuthConsumer)

so I want to pull/push from the logged in user's repository.

How can I use the Bitbucket REST APIs to do that with C# from an ASP.NET MVC application? I would like to implement my logic with the help of this documentation:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+Bitbucket+REST+APIs

I know there is a way to list a user repo with HTTP Authentication like this:

```
        string url = "https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/user/repositories/";
        var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

        string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username" + ":" + "password"));
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);

        using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

But how can I use the token value and secret to push/pull to repository?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the Documentation you sent, https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/repositories+Endpoint+-+1.0 - you cannot push/pull to the repository with the API, instead you use the normal way to interact with the git repo - using a commandline tool or whatnot.

You may only alter the meta-data through the API: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/repository+Resource+1.0#repositoryResource1.0-PUTarepositoryupdate

So just use the API client that is commandline: git

Comment: And if I know well, I also cannot use the API to interact with the mercurial repo? And what about Mercurial.NET, etc. libraries? With the help of these pushing/pulling is available as I know.

Comment: Yes, the API will not work with a mercurial repo.
Yes, a repository library will be able to work with a remote repo more than likely, I do not know Mercurial.NET myself.